# c++20 iterator concept application

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, c++-concepts

C++20 introduces concepts for iterators. However I somehow cannot figure out how to apply them on function templates.
Consider the following approach:

```
#include <iterator>

template <class T, class U>
concept Derived = std::is_base_of<U, T>::value;

template <typename Iterator>
requires std::input_iterator<Iterator>
Iterator test() {
    return Iterator();
}
```

Compilation fails for me with `error: no template named 'input_iterator' in namespace 'std'`.
The [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_iterator) doesn't give me any clue on what might be wrong.
Furthermore I couldn't find an example of an application of the iterator concepts online making it more difficult to find my mistake.
The `Derived` concept compiles successfully, which means that I am indeed using the correct C++ standard.

Does anyone have a clue on what might be going wrong?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/defdK6rsf). An outdated compiler perhaps?

Comment: Well that's dumb... I'm using Apple clang version 13.0.0 and thanks to your comment I've found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168181/apple-clang-13-c20-module-support-missing
So really seems to be a compiler issue. Would have guessed it would support C++20 without any issues.