# C++ 20 modules in Xcode 14.0.1

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, c++20, apple-m1

I would like to experiment with newer C++ features from (at least) C++20 and I'm new to C++ development on macOS in particular.

How do I enable importing of library headers in the 'module way'?

```
import <iostream>;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The build errors are

> Use of undeclared identifier 'iostream'

> Use of undeclared identifier 'std'

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70218679/3006011) and  tried installing llvm and I suppose that I *could* run the provided commands from the terminal, but I have not tried. Is there a way to make Xcode issue the commands provided in that answer (see below)? Where would I enter them in XCode? And what do they do? I'd like to avoid thinking about terminal commands and just have something that works.

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -std=c++20 -c -Xclang -emit-module-interface mathlib.cpp -o mathlib.pcm
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules -c -fprebuilt-module-path=. main.cpp -o main.o
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -std=c++2a -fmodules -o main main.o *.pcm
```

I saw that when making a new C++ project, Xcode defaults to the Apple Clang compiler and GNU++20 [-std=gnu++20] C++ Language dialect. There is also another option C++20 [-std=c++20] (what's the difference?) which I also tried, resulting in the same errors.

FYI, when I do `clang -v` I get

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

And a general question about other build systems such as CMake, which I discovered during my research for C++ compilation on mac. After making a CMake project, is it possible to use the regular IDE tools such as code suggestions and debugging?

Comment: Does Apple Clang version 14.0 support C++ modules?

Comment: `-std=gnu++20` is C++20 plus a few extra (non-standard) GNU features. If you write standard code, you will probably not notice any difference.