# Is there a way to compile on macos a project with cmakelists using c++20(modules,viewsy,range..)

Tags: c++, macos, c++-modules

I came across an article on this forum: [Apple Clang 13 C++20 Module Support Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168181/apple-clang-13-c20-module-support-missing)

But it is a bit compiled, I would like to make a project with cmake using modules.
But I do not know how to do it. I've been looking for info on this but I couldn't find the above link..

Comment: Shameless self promotion: https://github.com/royjacobson/modules-report. tl;dr modules won't be ready for CMake/Clang in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Watch [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5X803cXe02Y) for an overview of cmake + modules. The gist is: experimental support is in cmake, but they need support from compilers to make it stable.

As far as compilers go: msvc supports modules, g++ supports them with a custom patch (this might be in a release by now?) and as far as I know clang 13 supports them, while apple clang 13 does not.